# Is a context singleton okay in a single-user desktop application?

Tags: entity-framework

A single-user desktop application is unique in that you know the in-memory data is current.  So rather than going through the pain of creating a new context for intermittent database operations then reattaching objects, would using just one context for the entire application session carry any risks (other than a multi-user requirement arising later)?

Answer (score 0):

The context is 'transaction' based (i.e. for the commit). Therefore i would not make it a singleton.

I like this article: [Singleton datacontext](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2011/03/dont-use-singleton-datacontexts-entity.html) where it states that:

> A DataContext is lightweight and is not expensive to create

and

> You are probably saving a few 10s of milliseconds. The word micro optimisation springs to mind - in which case you probably shouldn't be using Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm guessing the transaction behaviour is configurable. While the other facts you state are true, they do not answer my question. That is, I would like to avoid the complexity of reattaching objects by using one context per app. I'm asking for risks this may carry.

Comment: Point taken. I did not digg deep enough into the Entity Framework to ansfer the question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The only risk of using a single `DataContext` is growing the change log too large, AFAIK, and exhausting the main memory or loosing lots of changes the user made in case of a crash. I'm not sure the transaction behaviour is configurable.

But you'll have to manage thread synchronization (as with any shared data in a multi-threaded application), so maybe you're better off using a `DataContext` per data operation - e.g. opening a `Form` to edit users in the app should open it's own `DataContext` and commit it on save or close.

Comment: If it is configurable then I guess your first point isn't an issue. I will find out.  Yes,thread sync issues could arise in the case of multiple thread. I'm actually not thinking about a simple forms UI with OK and Cancel buttons.

Comment: It's not about the actual `Form` per se, but about "actions" - stuff the user would do, following some predefined workflow.

Comment: Yes, I see.  But I'm thinking of an app in which reattaching objects to the context becomes quite complex.

Comment: There would be nothing to reattach, as soon as the workflow is completed, the `DataContext` is committed and the objects are destroyed (i.e. go out of scope and get reclaimed by the GC).

Comment: That is not how it works in my app. Domain objects are displayed on the main screen, so they need to continue existing throughout the application session.  It seems we are talking about two different kinds of UIs.